# If my application got approved and ready to release , but bymistake my app certificate get revoked, will my app get released?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

Suppose I have submitted my app to appstore, It reviewed and got approved by apple team and ready to be released. But in the mean while bymistake my app's certificate got revoked. Will my app get released or not.

Can anyone answer ?

Comment: Yes Yes Yes Yes

Answer (score 0):

As per what you have mentioned, if the build is uploaded and is in "Pending Developer Release" state, then you will be able to publish the app. Not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per following apple official document If your Apple Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected and distribution certificate is only used for uploading app on iTunes Connect.

[image: Apple official Documment]

You can find more details here : [Apple official Document](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/)